# Why is my code omitting the first database result?

Tags: php, mysql

As a noob, I can't figure this out, but I've got a feeling its fairly simple.

My first database result from the "markets" table is being omitted when I display the results.

```
<?php 
include('../includes/connection.php');

$sql="SELECT * FROM markets";
$sql_query = mysql_query($sql);
$post = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query);

$entries = mysql_num_rows($sql_query);

?>
```

The while loop:

```
            <?php while ($post = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query)) {?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                    <?php echo $post['id'] ?>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="td-actions text-left"><?php echo $post['category'] ?></td>
                                            <td class="td-actions text-left"><?php echo $post['date'] ?></td>
                                            <td class="td-actions text-left"><?php echo $post['dateupdated'] ?></td>
                                            <td class="td-actions text-right">
                                                <button name="edit" onclick="location.href='http://admin.ajidesign.xyz/edit.php?job=<?php echo $post['job'] ?>';" type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Edit Entry" class="btn btn-info btn-simple btn-xs">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                                                </button>

                                                <button onclick="warn()" name="remove" type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                                </button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: We need a bit more code, but it you likely need to while loop over the `mysql_fetch_array` line

Comment: Sorry! I thought the issue would be in that area. I am using a while loop which I've added in my edited question

Comment: the old mysql library is deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7 - see  the explanation under heading _Recommended API_ on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: @SamOnela I've heard this several times, I plan to convert my code as soon as I'm finished! For now I prefer to work with something familiar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the first row, and then don't do anything with it:

```
$post = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query);
```

Then you start looping over the remaining rows:

```
while ($post = mysql_fetch_array($sql_query)) {
```

It seems that you don't need that line of code which fetches the first row at all.  Let the loop be the first thing to call `mysql_fetch_array` on the query result and it'll start at the first record in the result.

Comment: Thank you for your help.. I feel like a buffoon! I appreciate your explanation

Comment: @SamiAji: You might be surprised how common this mistake is.  Personally I've never been a fan of the semantics of PHP's data access libraries, but they are what they are I suppose.